# Water coming into garage from outside when it rains, no basement

Tags: waterproofing

When it rains hard, water comes into the garage floor, from the outside garden. The floor in the garage gets totally wet. I do not know what to do. Does anyone have experience on this matter?

Comment: Welcome to the site. When you say "totally wet", are you saying the entire floor is damp, or are there puddles?

Comment: Is this water coming in under the garage door?

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement.  Please take the tour at https://diy.stackexchange.com/Tour to see the style that is expected of questions here.  More details such as photos, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

Change the grading so that the garden area is **lower than the garage floor** and **slopes away from the building by at least 1/8 inch per foot** (or "1 %", as 1/8 inch [1/96th of a foot] is very nearly 1/100 of a foot.) 
Or make it 1 centimeter per meter if that suits your local practices better. Try to maintain that slope away from the building for at least 12 feet or 4 meters.

I should perhaps say "fix" rather than "change" as I consider what you have to be evidently incorrect, if all-too-common.